# microsoft login with firebase vuejs

Tags: firebase, vue.js, azure-active-directory

I am working on a system which has a feature of sign in using microsoft I have integrated google and github they seem to work fine, but with microsoft I am getting the following error

```
You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead.
```

and now if i try to create an account using work email as you can see from the error above I get a error

```
You can't sign up here with a work or school email address. Use a personal email, such as Gmail or Yahoo!, or get a new Outlook email.
```

this is the vue code

```
async signInWithProvider(provider) {
  if (!this.User.Role) {
    this.LoginError = "Error: Role is Required!";
    return;
  }
  let instance = this;
  let service = null;

  if (provider == "microsoft.com") {
    service = new this.$firebase.auth.OAuthProvider(provider);
  } else {
    service = new this.$firebase.auth[provider]();
  }

  this.$firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPopup(service)
    .then(function(data) {
      instance.$store.dispatch("fetchUser", data.user);
      instance.$store.dispatch("fetchACL", instance.User.Role);

      //setting current rule according to selected from Form
      instance.$acl.change(instance.User.Role);

      instance.$router.replace({ name: "Home" });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      instance.$noty.error(
        "<span style='font-weight:bold'>Something went wrong!</span><br/>" +
          error.message
      );
    });
},
```

The credentials(client ID and secret) are set correctly from my azure account!
Any help?

Comment: Did you create the Azure AD app with the type as `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)`? See  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTg16.png.

Comment: yes i think I did that

Comment: Hi @uneebmeer are you still looking for any help here..?